# Why is Ajax not following success function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have done this hundreds of times and it seemed to work like a charm.But I just can't figure what is wrong with this code.

```js
$.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/sold_item",
        data:{qty:sold,tprice:sold_price,id:id,uprice:uprice},
        type:"post",
        async:true,
        success:function(msg){

            if(msg=="info_saved"){
                $('#sold_data').html('Your Sold Details Have Been Saved');
                setTimeout("$.colorbox.close()",1500);
              //  setTimeout("window.location.reload()",1800);
            }
            else if(msg=="wrong"){ 
                $('#sold_data').html('Your Information is Incorrect!!Enter Data Again!!');
                setTimeout("$.colorbox.close()",1500);
               // setTimeout("window.location.reload()",1800); 
            }
        }
    })
```

I am using condition for the response.The php code called by ajax is working perfectly
this is the exact code that I am using for ajax.I have `alerted the msg variable` and `firebug console` shows the same but the `if condition` is just not working.What can be the reason.I have tried `switch ..case` but to no avail.Please somebody see what I am not seeing.

Comment: Have you tried tracking the XMLHttpRequest in Chrome developer tools or Firebug? You should be able to see the entire response and track what exactly is coming back from your server

Comment: What exactly is your php page returning?  Are there any leading/trailing spaces that would cause a string comparison with "wrong" or "info_saved" to be false?

Comment: try `complete:`, maybe the the server return not `200` state code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the developer tools in chrome and go to the network tab and then select the XHR button at the bottom left of the screen. This will show you exactly what is happening and you can read the response or see an error if there is one.

Comment: I have solved my problem.My problem apparetly was that my php code sent some whitespaces and I trimmed the variable and the code is working perfectly.Thanks for the help.

Comment: not a problem. those developer tools are valuable thing to learn. I could not imagine writing javascript with out them

Answer (score -1):

Your URL seems wrong. `admin/sold_item` there is no file extension.

Comment: There could be some routing going on to give a more attractive url